# Custom ActionResult always returns empty string for "ContentType"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, content-type

I've got the following custom ActionResult. It works properly if I "Force" the ContentType, but the default behavior appears to be to retrieve an empty string as the ContentType

**C# Version**

```
public ActionResult Restful(Web.Mvc.Controller controller)
{
    // Test code
    var contentType = controller.Request.ContentType;
    // Above always returns ""

    switch (ResultType(controller)) {
        case RestfulResultType.Html:
            ViewResult result = new ViewResult();
            return result;
        case RestfulResultType.Json:
            JsonResult result = new JsonResult();
            return result;
        case RestfulResultType.JsonP:
            JsonPResult result = new JsonPResult();
            return result;
        case RestfulResultType.Xml:
            return new XmlResult(null);
        default:
            ViewResult result = new ViewResult();
            return result;
    }

}
```

**VB.NET Version**

```
    <Extension()>
    Public Function Restful(controller As Web.Mvc.Controller) As ActionResult

    ''# Test code
    Dim contentType = controller.Request.ContentType
    ''# Above always returns ""

        Select Case ResultType(controller)
            Case RestfulResultType.Html
                Dim result As New ViewResult()
                Return result
            Case RestfulResultType.Json
                Dim result As New JsonResult()
                Return result
            Case RestfulResultType.JsonP
                Dim result As New JsonPResult()
                Return result
            Case RestfulResultType.Xml
                Return New XmlResult(Nothing)
            Case Else
                Dim result As New ViewResult()
                Return result
        End Select

    End Function
```

Why wouldn't I be getting the appropriate contentType from this?

*PS: if you care what `ResultType` does, here it is.*

```
    Private Function ResultType(controller As Web.Mvc.Controller) As RestfulResultType

        Select Case LCase(controller.HttpContext.Request.ContentType)
            Case "text/html" : Return RestfulResultType.Html
            Case "application/json" : Return RestfulResultType.Json
            Case "text/javascript" : Return RestfulResultType.JsonP
            Case "application/javascript" : Return RestfulResultType.JsonP
            Case "application/x-javascript" : Return RestfulResultType.JsonP
            Case "text/xml" : Return RestfulResultType.Xml
            Case "application/xml" : Return RestfulResultType.Xml
            Case Else : Return RestfulResultType.Html
        End Select
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Request.ContentType is

> The mime type of the body of the request (**used with POST and PUT requests**)

You should inspect [HttpRequest.Accept](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.accept.aspx) header value

> Content-Types that are acceptable